# How can I change the letter assigned to a drive by Windows, without using a Windows program?

Tags: windows

I had Windows 7 installed on an old HDD, which contained my C:\ drive.

Perhaps foolishly (?), when I got a new SSD I first formatted it using the Windows Disk Management tool **and assigned it the drive letter S:\**.

This could well be where I went wrong. At this point I've been through all the business of cloning my old partition to the SSD, restoring/fixing the MBR, and even getting Windows to boot from the SSD. The only problem now is that it recognizes the drive as S:\ rather than C:\ (so effectively there *is* no C:\ drive), which seems to really be screwing Windows up.

I tried using diskpart.exe to assign the letter C:\ to the drive, but I get the following error (in a popup window):

```
S:\Windows\system32\diskpart.exe
The specified path does not exist.
```

This in spite of the fact that **I am trying to execute diskpart.exe from that very path!**

I could be wrong, of course; but I *highly* suspect that a missing C:\ drive is the root cause of this. I just want to change the letter of my S:\ drive to C:. Is this possible, perhaps using some external tool that I can boot into?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this done by following the steps outlined here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223188

Essentially I booted *into* Windows with my old C:\ drive present, then used **regedit** to reassign the drive lettters (since the Windows Disk Management tool wouldn't let me do it).